# Reset cellContent correctly (dequeueReusableCell)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, tableview

as you know tableViewCells can be displayed incorrectly after scrolling up and down, if you dont reset them in a certain way. After searching the internet without finding a satisfying answer, I would like to know how to do exactly that.

I am using one prototypeCell with an identifier that is reused. The titles and subtitles are currently stored in arrays. Depending on the indexpath, the specific string is taken from them. But how do i reset the content in a way, that the correct String is displayed? At the moment, the "incorrect" cell shows the title of the cell last initialised.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellNames[row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellDetails[row]
return cell
```

Thank you for answering

Comment: Can you show some codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, reset ALL the modified properties of the cell before returning it. That's it.

Comment: could specify how you would reset the title for example. by  assigning an empty string?

Comment: Just make sure to assign it to the relevant string or to an empty string if you have nothing tho put there.

Comment: Within in the arrays, there are both: Empty Strings and Strings with a content

Comment: Yeah, but make sure that you actually call cell.title.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; or similar in cellForRowAtIndexPath: . Make sure that this call is not ignored by a condition or anything